# How to write a function with tidy eval when using the "arrow" R package (arrow::open_dataset) and dplyr verbs?

Tags: r, dplyr, parquet, apache-arrow, tidyeval

#### What I'm trying to do

I'm attempting to write a function that uses dplyr verbs and that takes an "arrow open dataset" as the first argument, and a column in that dataset as the second argument. Since I would like to pass the column as a string (necessary for the context of my actual task I'm working on, i.e. *Shiny*), I'm using the syntax *.data[[.column]]*. Below is an image of the error I'm getting and some code to reproduce said error. Any help or insight is appreciated.

#### Image of error message

[image]

#### Code to reproduce error

```
# install.packages(c("dplyr", "ggplot2", "arrow"))
library(dplyr)

arrow::write_parquet(x = ggplot2::mpg, sink = "sample_data.parquet")

dat <- arrow::open_dataset("sample_data.parquet")

glimpse(dat)

get_metric <- function(.data, .metric) {
  
  .data %>%
    group_by(manufacturer, cyl) %>% 
    summarize(
      new_col = sum(.data[[.metric]], na.rm = T)
    ) %>% 
    ungroup() 
}

get_metric(dat, "cty") %>% collect()
```

#### Additional code that works but doesn't use arrow as much so not ideal for speed

In this code I collect before the tidy eval stuff so its just essentially regular dplyr code. It runs, but is a slower than code that I've successfully gotten to run before extracting stuff into said function.

```
get_metric2 <- function(.data, .metric) {
  
  .data %>%
    collect() %>% 
    group_by(manufacturer, cyl) %>% 
    summarize(
      new_col = sum(.data[[.metric]], na.rm = T)
    ) %>% 
    ungroup() 
}

get_metric2(dat, "cty")
```

Comment: If you're hoping to do this programmatically, is it safe to harc-code `manufacturer,cyl` in your function?

Comment: Yeah that's a fair point, thank you. I was just trying to keep the sample code as simple as possible. Do you have any idea of a solution to the actual problem though?

Per your suggestion, the second function be written like this:

get_metric2 <- function(.data, .metric, ...) {
  
  .data %>%
    collect() %>% 
    group_by(...) %>% 
    summarize(
      new_col = sum(.data[[.metric]], na.rm = T)
    ) %>% 
    ungroup() 
}

get_metric2(dat, "cty", manufacturer, cyl)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `!!` nomenclature.

```r
arrow::write_parquet(x = ggplot2::mpg, sink = "sample_data.parquet")
dat <- arrow::open_dataset("sample_data.parquet")

get_metric <- function(.data, .metric) {
  .metric <- rlang::sym(.metric)
  .data %>%
    group_by(manufacturer, cyl) %>% 
    summarize(
      new_col = sum(!!.metric, na.rm = T)
    ) %>% 
    ungroup() 
}

get_metric(dat, "cty") %>%
  collect()
# # A tibble: 32 × 3
#    manufacturer   cyl new_col
#    <chr>        <int>   <int>
#  1 audi             4     153
#  2 audi             6     148
#  3 audi             8      16
#  4 chevrolet        8     191
#  5 chevrolet        4      41
#  6 chevrolet        6      53
#  7 dodge            4      18
#  8 dodge            6     225
#  9 dodge            8     243
# 10 ford             8     197
# # ℹ 22 more rows
# # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. "cty" does exist btw. It's right there in your names(dat). Any ideas on why the "more new" syntax of .data[[.metric]] doesn't work, but the older !! does?

Comment: Yeah, I'm a dummy

Comment: The orchestration of lazy expressions into Arrow-friendly inner code is not as fast-paced or fully-extended to the lazy-data-variants that `dplyr` has introduced, I suspect that rlang's `!!` is handled before being handed to `arrow`, which makes it a lot more extensible and flexible in that regard.

Comment: Not at all, you helped me make the code work properly. Pretty funny though.

Comment: Admittedly, SO is not my full-time job, so multi-tasking takes a toll and introduces stupid mistakes like that, no matter how hard I try or my intentions :-/

Comment: Your explanation makes sense. Thanks again r2evans.

Comment: r2evans, *Yeah, I'm a dummy* -- what a ridiculous thing to say about r2evans :)